# DC Fan Malfunction Indicator

Tags: dc, fan, indicator

How can I make a simple circuit to trigger a buzzer for a 3-pin 12v DC fan when its stops working using the fan Sense/TACH/Yellow wire?

Comment: What signal do you get on the sense wire when the fan has stopped working?

Comment: Can I test this signal with a multimeter?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the yellow tacho wire is just a pulse stream proportional to the frequency. How about using a 555 timer configured as a 'missing pulse detector'? Choose a fan speed to trigger the alarm, and calculate the pulse timing (I believe the pulses are 2/rev) below which the circuit should trigger, and set the timer RC parameters for a pulse train of that timing. Any speed lower will then result in a 'missed pulse' output. This of course would be an intermittent output from the 555 (as another pulse does eventually arrive), so use another 555 or suitable circuit to 'latch' the output, until manually reset.

You could of course make R variable in the missing pulse detector circuit, allowing the alarm speed threshold to be adjusted.

Both the missing pulse monostable circuit and the latch can be done using a 556 dual timer rather than 2x 555's.

Comment: The problem with 555-based missing pulse detector is that if fan has stopped in a position that resets timer than alarm will never sound. You need DC decoupling to make this work.

Comment: which can be accomplished with a series capacitor

Comment: Yes, and which most likely will not if you do not point this out in your answer :)

Comment: The circuit mentioned above looks simpler than using the 555, however, I was hoping that I found an even more simple circuit without using an IC, something rely on transistors, resistors and caps, I'm a beginner in this field and building such circuits will take some time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean regular 12V PC fan with 3-pin Molex connector?
If yes then search web for something like "pc fan failure alarm". There are many circuits available, like [this one](http://pcbheaven.com/circuitpages/PC_Fan_Failure_Alarm/) for example.

Comment: Yes, the 12v PC fan, and thanks for the link, its what I was looking for.